# How to cross check 2 tables with exactly 2 duplicate entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables set up this way (postgres SQL):

Table X:
id
y_id
data

Table Y:
id
name

and Table X's "y_id" is a foreign key to Table Y's "id" field.

In Table X, there are multiple rows where data may be duplicated. In Table Y, there are possibly 2 rows with the same name, each with a different "id" field.

I would like to create a select statement that selects:

Rows that are having exactly 2 duplicate "data", and only the rows with different "Y.name" field are considered different.

For example:
Table X:

```
1 100 data1
2 101 data2
3 102 data2
4 103 data3
5 104 data3
```

Table Y:

```
100 foo
101 bar
102 bar
103 foofoo
104 foobar
```

I want to be able to return "data3" in this example, but not "data2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on the use case you listed, and if I understand you correctly it should work any time there are exactly two different names for an x.id:

```
with only_two as (
  select
    x.id
  from
    table_x x
    join table_y y on x.y_id = y.id
  group by x.id
  having
    count (distinct y.name) = 2
)
select *
from table_x x
join only_two t on x.id = t.id
```

Comment: Instead of "x.id", it should be "x.data". But otherwise this works in my use case. Thanks!